# Layout questions about HDivideBox and HGroup

Tags: apache-flex, layout, flex4, flex4.5, divide

I'm struggling with 2 layout problems when using HDivideBox in Flex 4.5:

[image]

1. When I drag the vertical dividing bar to the left, the Label and the 3 RadioButtons on the top-left do not break in 2 rows. Instead the overlap with the Label on the top right. Is there please a way to make it more flexible.
2. For some reason I can't drag the vertical dividing bar to the right anymore than at the screenshot above. And I need to do that a bit, so that 3 rectangles can be shown in the List on the left.

Below is my code, please advise me.

```
<mx:HDividedBox height="100%">

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="justify">
    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="baseline">
        <s:Label text="Игровые столы:" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Все" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Свободные" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Полные" />
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:List itemRenderer="Game" dataProvider="{_games}" height="100%">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout />
        </s:layout>
    </s:List>   
</s:VGroup> 

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="justify">
    <s:Label text="Игроки в лобби:" verticalAlign="bottom" />
</s:VGroup> 

</mx:HDividedBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part of the question. You can use some kind of flow layout instead of horizontal layout for your labels and radio buttons on the left side. For example [this layout](http://kachurovskiy.com/2010/horizontal-multiline-layout/#more-97).

The second part is related to the min width of the container. Try to change it. Something like the following:

```
<mx:HDividedBox height="100%">

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="justify">
    <s:HGroup verticalAlign="baseline">
        <s:Label text="Игровые стулья:" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Все" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Свободные" />
        <s:RadioButton groupName="_group" label="Полные" />
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:List itemRenderer="Game" dataProvider="{_games}" height="100%">
        <s:layout>
            <s:TileLayout />
        </s:layout>
    </s:List>   
</s:VGroup> 

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="justify" minWidth="50">
    <s:Label text="Игроки в лобби:" verticalAlign="bottom" />
</s:VGroup> 

</mx:HDividedBox>
```

Comment: Unfortunately minWidth="50" does not help - still can not drag the bar to the right

Comment: But was something changed with drag possibility?

Comment: Oh, actually I was missing width="100%" for the HDivideBox itself. I wonder if I could enabled borders somehow for components/containers while debugging layouts.

Comment: And for the 1st part I wonder if it can be done by the "core" s:Group without introducing 3rd party layouts/containers

Comment: Flex SDK hasn't out of the box flow layout containers.

Comment: 1 more question: do you please have an idea how to align the right Label? Currently it is above the left Label and RadioButtons

Comment: Try to use something like `<s:Label text="Игроки в лобби:" verticalAlign="bottom" paddingTop="5" />`.